# Is there something like a FOR loop in MySql?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a table with matches information, and I need to return a row for each goal and each team. So for example:

```
+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|  Match | Team1 | goal1 | goal2 | Team2 |
+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|    1   | Red   |   1   |   0   | Blue  |   
+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|    2   | Green |   2   |   1   | Black |   
+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

I want to run a function for each row that returns a row for each goal for each team. So my function result would be:

```
+--------+-------+-------+
|  Goal  | Match | Team  |
+--------+-------+-------+
|    1   |   1   |  Red  |  
+--------+-------+-------+
|    2   |   2   | Green | 
+--------+-------+-------+
|    3   |   2   | Green |  
+--------+-------+-------+
|    4   |   2   | Black | 
+--------+-------+-------+
```

My ultimate objective is that I need to have one row for each match/team/goal to fill in manually the Scorer and the minute. Since I hace over 40000 matches, copy pasting each row counting the amount of goals is a pain.

I would like to start with a goal table pre populated with as much information as I already have.

Comment: a Cursor is about the closest equivalent, but they're slow and verbose. SQL is far better at set-based operations (e.g. select and update). But in this case what you're probably looking for is a Pivot type of operation, I think

Comment: Create a table t2 with the 5 columns you want, then use the `INSERT INTO t2 SELECT c1, c2, c3 FROM t1` construct to fill in the goals.

Comment: Yeah performance is not a concern because I need to actually export that and fill in the data manually in a Google sheet. That function will only run once in a life time hehe

Comment: Why isn't Blue in the results?

Comment: Oh, I see, Blue never scored any goals, so it doesn't get a row.

Comment: @Barmar cause 0 goals

Answer (score 1):

Create a table that contains numbers from 1 to the maximum number of possible goals, i.e.

```
CREATE TABLE numbers (
    num INT PRIMARY KEY
);
INSERT INTO numbers VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), ...
```

You can then join this table with your original table:

```
SELECT num AS Goal, `Match`, Team
FROM numbers
JOIN (
    SELECT Team1 AS Team, goal1 AS goals, `Match`
    FROM matches
    UNION
    SELECT Team2 AS Team, goal2 AS goals, `Match`
    FROM matches
) ON num <= goals
```

Answer (score -1):

While loop syntax example in MySQL:

```
delimiter //

CREATE procedure yourdatabase.while_example()
wholeblock:BEGIN
  declare str VARCHAR(255) default '';
  declare x INT default 0;
  SET x = 1;

  WHILE x <= 5 DO
    SET str = CONCAT(str,x,',');
    SET x = x + 1;
  END WHILE;

  select str;
END//
```

Which prints:

```
mysql> call while_example();
+------------+
| str        |
+------------+
| 1,2,3,4,5, |
+------------+
```

FOR loop syntax example in MySQL:

```
delimiter //

CREATE procedure yourdatabase.for_loop_example()
wholeblock:BEGIN
  DECLARE x INT;
  DECLARE str VARCHAR(255);
  SET x = -5;
  SET str = '';

  loop_label: LOOP
    IF x > 0 THEN
      LEAVE loop_label;
    END IF;
    SET str = CONCAT(str,x,',');
    SET x = x + 1;
    ITERATE loop_label;
  END LOOP;

  SELECT str;

END//
```

Which prints:

```
mysql> call for_loop_example();

    +-------------------+
    | str               |
    +-------------------+
    | -5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0, |
    +-------------------+
    1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Tutorial: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/stored-procedures-loop.aspx